# Please how to sum xml with a java program

Tags: java, xml, sum

```
<home>
    <price> 10 </price>
    <price> 20 </price>
    <price> 30 </price>
    <price> 40 </price>
    <price> 50 </price>
</home>
```

Please how to sum xml  with a java program

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HobbyReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory =
                    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder parser =
                    factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = parser.parse("transactions.xml");
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("home");
        double value=0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++)
        {
            org.w3c.dom.Node nNode = nList.item(i);

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
            {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                String price = eElement.getElementsByTagName("price").item(0).getTextContent(); // example String
                value = value  + Double.parseDouble(price);

            }
        }

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                    System.out.println("Price: " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("price").item(0).getTextContent());

                }
            }
        System.out.println(value);
    }
    }
```

i need to have tue sum. 150
Cependant, ce que j'essaie de comprendre, c'est s'il est possible de prendre les valeurs qui représentent les valeurs de "prix" que je tire déjà et d'en trouver la somme?

Comment: I don’t understand the last part of your question, but you should consider xpath to get all the <price /> element‘s content at once.

Comment: However, what I am trying to figure out is, is it possible to take the values that represent the "price" values I am already pulling, and find the sum of them?

Comment: Shouldn’t this be already in `value`?

Comment: You loop for each `home` tag, and only get the first `price` from each `home`.

Comment: but how i can do it? i can t have the summing, 150